# App crashing in Android Studio when I run the debugger

Tags: android-studio

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 and whenever I try to debug an app in Android Studio the app crashes and disconnects the phone from the PC.

I don't know if it's the drivers for the phone that I need to re-install or if there is a bug in the operating system or maybe something else.

I'm running Android Studio 3.1 under Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia edition, and I'm running KDE.

Comment: Consider asking on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Tidied up question

Comment: Tidied up question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a driver for Linux. You can get it from here:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip

try following these steps to set it up correctly (I have it from https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)

1. Extract the ZIP to an easily-accessible location (like the Desktop for example).
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Enter the following command: cd /path/to/extracted/folder/
4. This will change the directory to where you extracted the ADB files.
   So for example:cd /Users/Doug/Desktop/platform-tools/
5. Connect your device to your Linux machine with your USB cable. Change the connection mode to “file transfer (MTP)” mode. This is not always necessary for every device, but it’s recommended so you don’t run into any issues.
6. Once the Terminal is in the same folder your ADB tools are in, you can execute the following command to launch the ADB daemon: adb devices
7. Back on your smartphone or tablet device, you’ll see a prompt asking you to allow USB debugging. Go ahead and grant it.install adb
8. Finally, re-enter the command from step #7. If everything was successful, you should now see your device’s serial number in the Terminal window output.

Comment: Thanks soo much the adb is working way better now 

Comment: What about windows :D